# Using Enquire.js with Vue.js to query about the browser's size

Tags: javascript, vue.js, enquire.js

I'm using [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#quick-start) with *Vue.js* to query the browser's size and update two data properties accordingly. So, if I do this:

```
ready: function() {
    // Listen for changes in the browser's size
    window.addEventListener("resize",
    enquire.register("screen and (max-width:400px)", {
        match: function() {
            this.displayIsLarge = false;
            this.displayIsSmall = true;
            console.log("the screen is now small");
        },
        unmatch: function() {
            this.displayIsLarge = true;
            this.displayIsSmall = false;
            console.log("the screen is now large");
        }
    })
    );
}
```

It will output the correct message in the console (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/932fu9ox/10/)), however it's not changing the value of `displayIsLarge` and `displayIsSmall`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the scope of `this`. The full working code would be:

```
ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    // Listen for changes in the browser's size
    window.addEventListener("resize",
    enquire.register("screen and (max-width:400px)", {
        match: function() {
            self.displayIsSmall = true;
            self.displayIsLarge = false;
            console.log("the screen is now small");
        },
        unmatch: function() {
            self.displayIsLarge = true;
            self.displayIsSmall = false;
            console.log("the screen is now large");
        }
    })
    );
}
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/932fu9ox/12/)